# IE8 removes margin bottom on mouseover

Tags: jquery, html, css

[My website](http://singhharmeet.com/akhileshsir/)

All is well in other browsers and even IE7 but only on ie8 after mouse over the menu, the margin bottom on the li(s) gets removed. Also the font-face is not working in chrome for some reason.

Comment: The website looks fine. I cannot replicate the issue. But you should put the html and css related to the issue in the question.

Comment: Those bouncing menus give me a headache!

Comment: @Barmar, care to provide any better solution to that ?

Comment: @tw16, I tagged html css into the question.

Comment: It might be less annoying if it closed one menu before opening the next, instead of doing them both at the same time.

Comment: No Harmeet, I am saying you need to put the relevant html and css **code** into the question. Not just tag it html and css. But also as I say, I cannot replicate the issue in IE8. Maybe take a screen shot as well.

Comment: @tw16 : http://jsfiddle.net/harmeet_jaipur/U2nqs/ Here it is. The javascript is a little buggy, i am fairly new to jquery so please let me know if there are better alternate to what i have done. Thanks

Comment: I am afraid I still cannot replicate the issue. The bottom margins look fine to me. Maybe take a screen shot showing the issue. Make sure you edit the question with new information, don't post it in the comments or people might not see it.

Comment: I have resolved the issue but now i am facing a new one. If you can please visit http://singhharmeet.com/akhileshsir/ and see the issue that i am having now which is : I have applied an accordion like script and when i mouseover the about tab or contact tab, the previously opened submenu wont close.

Comment: How did you resolve your issue? Please answer your question yourself so others facing the same issue can find an answer. Thank you!